# Insert value from code behind to asp.net tag

Tags: asp.net

I have a script manager in my code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="masterScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"
            EnablePartialRendering="true" ScriptMode="Auto" AsyncPostBackTimeout="360">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/web_resource.ashx?type=1&v=<%=version %>" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And I would like to add version info at the end of Path in script reference. I tried also with `<%#` but I only see encoded characters but not version number. What should I change?

Comment: Probably you'll need to add this reference in page's or control's code-behind (i.e. Load event).

Comment: yeah, that worked, please add answer :)

Comment: Here's is the answer. I was 99% sure of the answer, but as I can't check if it was working in a sample project... :)

Comment: Some time ago I published a project that's an actual ASP.NET AJAX replacement and it has better dependency management (and other things). It's 100% open soruce and I'm looking either for contributors or adopters! http://calipso.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be just adding this script reference in control's or page's code-behind during some of control/page life-cycle events (i.e. `Load`).